If all Sefer torahs are possibly passul, how do we say a Bracha on reading it?
There are a few discrepancies in the Torah regarding spelling of specific words. These differences make no difference in the meaning. However, because a Sefer Torah is passul even if one letter is incorrect and the meaning is not affected, how can we say a Bracha on receiving an Aliyah to a Seder Torah that is safek kosher?

" a Sefer Torah is passul even if one letter is incorrect" Maybe this is not correct?

"A Torah Scroll is disqualified if even a single letter is added.
A Torah Scroll is disqualified if even a single letter is deleted." https://aish.com/48969731/

maybe we don't actually hold that way? (Indeed this is disputed)

Why do you think we can't read from an invalid scroll? The words you say will be the real ones.

Where is this disputed? Also, an invalid scroll is invalid to be read and uses from; it is like a regular Chumash. Finally, even if you could read from the undisputed parts with a Bracha, we even read even the disputed parts with a Bracha?!

"an invalid scroll is invalid to be read and uses from" You assert your conclusion but maybe it's just invalid to fulfill the commandment to write a Torah, but we can still learn publicly from it.

We rely on the Chazoke (presumption) of correctness until proven otherwise. The same can be said for many other Mitzvos, like Teffilin, Brochos on food, and more.
